# Including username in Alembic migration file header

Tags: python, database-migration, alembic

as the title suggests I wish to include the name of the developer generating the migration file within its header when using the auto generation tool. The format of the migration header is set in the script.py.mako file and can include different variables such as revision_id or date and time of creation. Here is my current header definition:

```
"""
Revision ID: ${up_revision}
Revises: ${down_revision}
Create Date: ${create_date}
Message: ${message}
"""
```

I would like to add to this a *Owner* field and attach it to the unix username using something like python's getpass(). However, I do not know where to ${x} variables are retrieved from and how I would set more of these variables.
The only alternative solution I can think of at the moment is to create a hook (function run after migration) which would modify the file after the fact.
Thanks!